# Replace double quotations with brackets in a Python List of Strings

Tags: python, string, list, text-processing, naivebayes

This is the format of my List currently:

```
["'There's no going back', 'pop'", "'Mark my words', 'pop'", "'This love will make you levitate', 'pop'", "'Like a bird, like a bird without a cage', 'pop'"]
```

I want to convert it to the following format:

```
[('There\'s no going back', 'pop'), ('Mark my words', 'pop'), ('This love will make you levitate', 'pop'), ('Like a bird, like a bird without a cage', 'pop')]
```

So I need to tokenize the input strings into tuples. But I'm not sure how can this be done since the "" are present as it is primarily a String.

If additional context is required, I'm scraping a large chunk of data in the above mentioned format and to process it with a Naive Bayes Classifier I need it in the bracket format. I'm open to try a different approach if it's more efficient.

Comment: This would be so much easier if you didn't have apostrophes inside your inner strings.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: It is unclear what your expected output is, since what you provided is not a valid Python literal/expression.

Comment: The provided input and output are definitely valid, the first is a list of strings and the second is a list of tuples. The first is a string of the raw input and the second is the string tokenized into a tuple.

Comment: @PrianshShah it is not, it is a syntax error, which should obvious from the syntax highlighting. It's also unclear because `"` is part of the *string object representation*. Although yours is a reasonable interpretation.

Comment: The syntax highlighting issue is caused by the first element of the first tuple, which has an unescaped '; you can get the output desired by doing `[x.replace("'",'').split(', ') for x in xs]` for sure. If it helps I've gone ahead and edited the original question to escape the string and allow syntax highlighting.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to Python so it never occurred to me that my output was indeed a List of Tuples. My problem has been solved though.

Comment: Also my expressions are valid as explained above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `replace` and `split`:

```
lst = ["'There's no going back', 'pop'", "'Mark my words', 'pop'", "'This love will make you levitate', 'pop'", "'Like a bird, like a bird without a cage', 'pop'"]

print([tuple(x.replace('\'', '').split(',')) for x in lst])
```

**Output**:

```
[('Theres no going back', ' pop'), ('Mark my words', ' pop'), ('This love will make you levitate', ' pop'), ('Like a bird', ' like a bird without a cage', ' pop')]
```

Comment: It should be noted that there are both performance gains and losses when casting to Tuple. If OP needs this in a constant use context, then `tuple()` is an O(n) operation and could be inefficient. However if preprocessing occurs at the very beginning and time is not sensitive, then `tuple` uses less memory than list when being stored and so is more efficient (with the examples given, tuple uses 64 bits while list uses 160)

Comment: @PrianshShah Yes preprocessing occurs at the very beginning. Also I'm referring to the nltk Naive Bayes classifier, so this format is all that it accepts.